# How Marmalade support text-to-speech?

Tags: marmalade, text-to-speech

Is there any API/SDK to support tts (text to speech) in Marmalade?

Answer (score 1):

I've had some success porting Flite (http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/flite/) to the Marmalade environment. It produces wave files and raw, in-memory buffers (which can then be played using s3eSound directly) fine.

The s3eSound adapter (which plays the text directly from within flite) is a work in progress, so, while it does produce something close to recognisable speech, it is also obviously bugged. For my purposes, the raw buffers are more useful anyway, but feel free to try to fix it up.

You can see what I've done here https://github.com/madmaw/marmalade-flite

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific API provided by Marmalade however you may be able to use the EDK if native APIs provide this functionality on iOS or Android.
https://www.madewithmarmalade.com/devnet/docs#/main/extensions.html